# Sauce Labs - connecting with BDD cucumber - Mac OS 10.13

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I'm getting the following error when I connect to Sauce labs after upgrading my machine from Mac OS 10.12 to 10.13

```
**com.saucelabs.ci.sauceconnect.SauceConnectFourManager prepAndCreateProcess
Launching Sauce connect 4.4.2....**
```

And stops right here. There is no change in POM, username, pwd provided for sauce connect.

> Sauce-rest-version is 1.0.35 sauce-connect-plugin is 2.1.23

Logs shows the below error :

```
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ 
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ 
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ 
[FATAL] The parents form a cycle: commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 -> com.saucelabs:sauce-connect:3.1.32 -> com.saucelabs:sauce-connect:3.1.3
```

Is there anyone who has similar issue ? What could be the fix?